# Counting cells in table with condition - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new in VBA and try to build code which is going to count number of cells with the same value in a row (also ideally I want it to count cells and starts if cell have different value than last one (I want to build trends which show me how many weeks project is in last state). So I buil something like this:

```
Sub Loop2()

Dim rw As Long
Dim cl As Long
Dim tb1 As ListObject
Dim tRows As Long
Dim tCols As Long
Dim n As Integer

n = 1

Set tb1 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

With tb1.DataBodyRange
    tRows = .Rows.Count
    tCols = .Columns.Count
End With

MsgBox tRows & " " & tCols

For rw = 2 To rw = tRows
    For cl = 2 To cl = tCols
        If Cells(rw, cl).Value = Cells(rw, cl + 1).Value Then
            n = n + 1
        ElseIf Cells(rw, cl).Value <> Cells(rw, cl + 1).Value Then
            n = 1
        End If
    Next cl
    Cells(rw, tCols + 1).Value = n
Next rw


End Sub
```

It compiles but it does not give me a result (I just have a msg box). Loops do not work. Can you give me tips what I am doing wrong here, please?

I suspect that everything :D

Comment: Try changing this (and following line similarly) to `For rw = 2 To tRows`.

Comment: Why not use a formula as you're putting the vals in `tcol+1` ?

Comment: Because I want to do all tasks by klicking only one button in Interphase (I have sereral operation before it)

Comment: Your `If...Then` sentence increases `n` if 1 cell and adjacent one got same value, but if not, it **restarts** the count to 1. Besides, ¿what if cells got same values but they are not adjacent? Something like `1,2,3,1,4,5,` would return 1 in your code, when number 1 appears twice. And finally. you want to count every value how many times? just 1 column? Maybe a data example (input) and the expected output will help this question.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help I changed cl+1 to cl - 1 and it works as expected!

Comment: @darson Same applies, do what you need, then add the formula....  I'll leave you to it.  `IF` `<>` and `COUNTIF` would assist :)

Comment: Thanks - I will try easier approach as well :) Thanks @Nathan_Sav